# What is causing my Areca Dypsis to die?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves

I bought my **Areca Dypsis** plant a month ago and very quickly I noticed that the leaves were turning yellow, and others weren't really growing.

I don't overwater my plant and it doesn't receive direct sunlight. It also has little black spots on the stems but not on the leaves.

- Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should do?
- Should I cut off the leaves that are completely dried out?

Pictures:

These leaves never actually fully developed
[image]

Lots of broken branches and brown leaves
[image]

The stems
[image]

Comment: What sort of store did you buy at? Is it possible they "greened it up" before selling it? Things like ramping the fertilizer and sticking it under grow lights and such.

Comment: I bought it at a plant festival and all the other plants I bought there have thrived so I don't think they did anything to it.